# Rails: How to load a thread on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, configuration, udp, initialization

I am working with a UDP server in rails and I have the server called from my config/initializers folder. 
If I run the code `thread_a=Thread.new{UDPserver()}` then the the code works fine however the code eventually switches off, I presume once my rails script stops running.
If I write

```
thread_a=Thread.new{UDPserver()}
thread_a.join
```

then my whole web program doesn't work and I presume this is because my program is waiting till the threads finish (which they don't) until it loads up the rest of the program.
What am I to do?

Notes:

The reason I am running a thread is because I need my program to be constantly waiting for UDP messages and then to react.  Also, I need my standard we program to be up at the same time.

ruby 1.9.3p194

Rails 3.2.12

Comment: Why does the code switch off?  Maybe you are having an error if it is meant to run forever.

Comment: no, there is no error.  I actually implemented this with a fork and its working fine.  It turned off because I didn't use a join.  However, if I used a join then the code wouldn't progress past the particular file I was working in.  I guess this is just a quirk of rails.